# Batch file FOR loop won't loop

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, for-loop

I'm doing an assignment. Trying to get my batch file to read individual lines of an input file and figure out how many dots and commas it has. However, no matter what I do, the loop only runs once, so only the first line of the file is correctly processed, even though there are multiple lines. What am I missing?

```
REM @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=-2
for /F "delims=" %%I in (laba2.txt) DO (
set initial=%%I
set b = !initial!
:againdot
set oldb=!b!
set "b=!b:*.=!"
set /a count+=1
echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againdot
set b=!initial!
:againcomma
set oldb=!b!
set "b=!b:*,=!"
set /a count+=1
echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againcomma
)
echo %count%
```

I have, of course, read other similar questions, but I can't figure out how, if at all, those apply to my problem, so sorry if this is a duplicate.

Oh, and if you have a better way to count individual characters, I'd be happy to hear it, but that's besides the point.

EDIT: here's CMD feed

```
C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>test.bat

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>REM @echo off

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set count=-2

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>for /F "delims=" %I in (laba2.txt) DO (
set initial=%I
 set b = !initial!
 set oldb=!b!
 set "b=!b:*.=!"
 set /a count+=1
 echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
 if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againdot
 set b=!initial!
 set oldb=!b!
 set "b=!b:*,=!"
 set /a count+=1
 echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
 if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againcomma
)

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>(
set initial=this,is .a random
 set b = !initial!
 set oldb=!b!
 set "b=!b:*.=!"
 set /a count+=1
 echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
 if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againdot
 set b=!initial!
 set oldb=!b!
 set "b=!b:*,=!"
 set /a count+=1
 echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
 if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againcomma
)
"b = *.=, oldb = "

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set oldb=!b!

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set "b=!b:*.=!"

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set /a count+=1

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
"b = =, oldb = *.="

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againdot

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set oldb=!b!

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set "b=!b:*.=!"

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set /a count+=1

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
"b = =, oldb = ="

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againdot

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set b=!initial!

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set oldb=!b!

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set "b=!b:*,=!"

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set /a count+=1

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
"b = is .a random, oldb = this,is .a random"

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againcomma

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set oldb=!b!

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set "b=!b:*,=!"

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>set /a count+=1

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>echo "b = !b!, oldb = !oldb!"
"b = is .a random, oldb = is .a random"

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>if not !oldb! == !b! goto :againcomma

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>echo 3
3

C:\Users\fiksi\Desktop\Учёбка\ОС 3с\Лаба 2>
```

And here's the file I'm trying to read:

```
this,is .a random
..,arran,gement of.

commas  and,
 dots
```

Comment: @echo on might actually show you the problem.

Comment: I have my echo on. It says nothing. Nothing I can decipher anyway.

Comment: You suggest that it sometimes works. Maybe explain that and show your research and debugging results.

Comment: It doesn't work "sometimes", it works for the first line only. Maybe I'm not very clear on that, let me fix that

Comment: Folks here will expect you to show the results of your research. Be very clear what you see when you run the script.

Comment: Here's the debug info. Still not seeing it. Maybe I don't know where to look? That's perfectly plausible.

Comment: You can't do a go-to wthin a FOR command.

Comment: There we go! That's something.
The question now, though, is what do I do then? I'm not sure I can count those without a goto.
Also, just for the sake of curiosity: why can't I do a goto? What happens?

Comment: Have you trying putting subroutines outside the loop?

Comment: Windows command processor does not support jump to a label inside body of __FOR__. Labels inside body of __FOR__ result in an undefined behavior of script execution. You could use a subroutine although that would dramatically increase the batch file execution time. See [Why is a GOTO loop much slower than a FOR loop and depends additionally on power supply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362979/) to see how one task was solved with four different solutions and how long it take to finish the task with each solution.

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting my answer in case you find it helpful or leave feedback about it. See https://stackoverflow/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Windows command processor does not support jump to a label inside body of FOR. Labels inside body of FOR result in an undefined behavior of script execution.

<sup>@Mofi said in comments</sup>

So, you can't do it that way! If understood you want to make a batch file which will find how many dots and commas a file has. I have changed your file entirely and wrote a new one:

```bat
@echo off

set /a "count_dots=0"
set /a "count_commas=0"

powershell.exe -NoP -C "(Get-Content laba2.txt) -Replace '!',''|Set-Content $env:TEMP\laba2_tmp.txt"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims= eol=" %%A IN (%TEMP%\laba2_tmp.txt) do (
    set line=%%A

    rem Find size of variable:
    (echo !line!)>%TEMP%\temp.txt
    for %%B IN (%TEMP%\temp.txt) do set size=%%~zB

    rem Check if the line has got commas:
    if not "!line:,=!" == "!line!" (
        rem Find size of variable *without* commas:
        (echo !line:,=!)>%TEMP%\temp.txt
        for %%B IN (%TEMP%\temp.txt) do set sizecommas=%%~zB

        rem Find difference of previous and new size of variable:
        if !size! NEQ !sizecommas! (set /a "diffcommas=size-sizecommas" & set /a "count_commas+=diffcommas")


    rem Check if the line has got dots:
    if not "!line:.=!" == "!line!" (
        rem Find size of variable *without* dots:
        (echo !line:.=!)>%TEMP%\temp.txt
        for %%B IN (%TEMP%\temp.txt) do set sizedots=%%~zB

        rem Find difference of previous and new size of variable:
        if !size! NEQ !sizedots! (set /a "diffdots=size-sizedots" & set /a "count_dots+=diffdots")
        )
    )
)

rem Delete temporary files:
del %TEMP%\temp.txt %TEMP%\laba2_tmp.txt

if %count_dots% == 1 (echo Found %count_dots% dot in specified document.) else (echo Found %count_dots% dots in specified document.)
if %count_commas% == 1 (echo Found %count_commas% comma in specified document.) else (echo Found %count_commas% commas in specified document.)

pause
```

Yes, it's true that it is quite big, but I couldn't simplify it further for a reason :)!

This file:

- Sets wanted variables to `0`.
- Has a `for` loop which loops through `laba2.txt` textfile.

  - Only if line (`%%A`) contains dots (`.`) or commas (`,`) will be processed.
  - Finds size of line with another `for` loop.
  - Finds size of line **without** dots (`.`).
  - Does the same for commas (`,`).
  - In both cases we find difference of previous size of line and current size of line. We sum the result in the corresponding variable (`%count_dots%` or `%count_commas%`)
- `echo` the variables
- Remove temporary files.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend first reading [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) and look on the line `set b = !initial!` which defines an environment variable with name `b`  (case-insensitive interpreted small letter B and space) with a space and the line read from text file as value.

Windows command processor does not support a jump to a label inside body of **FOR**.
Labels inside body of **FOR** result in an undefined behavior of script execution.

It is possible to use a subroutine although that dramatically increases the batch file execution time. See [Why is a GOTO loop much slower than a FOR loop and depends additionally on power supply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362979/) to see how one task was solved with four different solutions and how long it take to finish the task with each solution.

Here is my solution for this task calling a subroutine for every line to count commas and dots in current line:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "TotalCountComma=0"
set "TotalCountDot=0"

for /F "usebackq delims= eol=" %%I in ("laba2.txt") do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    call :Count
)

if %TotalCountComma% == 1 (set "CommaS=") else set "CommaS=s"
if %TotalCountDot% == 1 (set "DotS=") else set "DotS=s"
echo The file contains %TotalCountComma% comma%CommaS% and %TotalCountDot% dot%DotS%.
endlocal
goto :EOF

:Count
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "LineCountComma=0"
set "LineCountDot=0"
set "LineLength=1"
for /L %%J in (0,1,8192) do (
    if "!Line:~%%J,1!" == "" goto ExitLoop
    if "!Line:~%%J,1!" == "," set /A LineCountComma+=1
    if "!Line:~%%J,1!" == "." set /A LineCountDot+=1
)
:ExitLoop
endlocal & set /A "TotalCountComma+=%LineCountComma%" & set /A "TotalCountDot+=%LineCountDot%"
goto :EOF
```

**FOR** with option `/F` reads text file `laba2.txt` line by line and ignores empty lines.

There are ignored by default by **FOR** also all lines starting with a semicolon because of `eol=;` is the default for end of line option. This behavior is changed with `eol=` which specifies no end of line character.

**FOR** splits up by default every line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assigns just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here, too. `delims=` defines an empty list of delimiters which disables the line splitting behavior.

Option `usebackq` is used because of the string in double quotes should be interpreted as file name of which lines should be read and not as string to process. In this special case the double quotes around file name `laba2.txt` would not be necessary which would make also usage of `usebackq` useless.

`delims=` **and** `eol=` can be specified in a double quoted options string, but only in this order. `"usebackq eol= delims="` would not work because of this defines space as end of line character and an empty list of delimiters.

So **FOR** with the used options assigns every non-empty line read from specified file to specified loop variable `I` and runs the commands inside body of **FOR** loop.

The line is assigned next to environment variable with name `Line`. This is done while delayed environment variable expansion is disabled which is important on current line containing one or more exclamation marks. Otherwise Windows command processor would parse with enabled [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) the command line `set "Line=%%I"` a second time after replacing `%%I` by current value of loop variable `I` and would interpret `!` as beginning/end of an environment variable of which value is referenced delayed. This behavior is definitely not wanted here as it would result in modifying the line on assigning it to environment variable `Line` with in most cases removing parts of the line.

But delayed expansion is necessary to count the commas and dots in a line. It would be possible to enable delayed expansion after the command line `set "Line=%%I"` with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and use `endlocal` as last command line in body of **FOR** loop. But this is not possible here. For the reason read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) with details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

Therefore a subroutine is called with `call :Count` to process the current line. The subroutine uses a **FOR** loop with option `/L` to compare every character of current line against `,` and `.` and which is exited on reaching end of line with a jump to a label below the **FOR** loop. This **FOR** loop speeds up line processing dramatically in comparison to a pure **GOTO** loop which would be also possible, but is much slower.

The command line after `:ExitLoop` is again something special. The command `endlocal` would restore previous environment which means the environment variables `LineCountComma` and `LineCountDot` do not exist anymore, at least not with the values set above and inside the **FOR** loop of the subroutine. So there are three commands specified on one command line which `cmd.exe` executes one after the other because of operator `&` whereby `%LineCountComma%` and `%LineCountDot%` are replaced by the current values of those two environment variables before executing this command line with the three commands. So `endlocal` deletes the environment variables `LineCountComma` and `LineCountDot`, but their values are already as strings on the command line and therefore the values pass the local environment barrier.

After reading every line from text file and processing every non-empty line in subroutine `Count`, the values of the two total counts are output before restoring the initial environment and exiting batch file execution with `goto :EOF` (if command extensions were enabled before starting this batch file as by Windows default).

I recommend reading [Why does Windows have a limit on environment variables at all?](https://superuser.com/questions/1070272/) regarding to value `8192` for maximum string length. In the code above is used `set "Line=%%I"`. The maximum length of the line read from text file can be `8183` characters in this case because of command processor limit of `8191` bytes **minus** `4` bytes for variable name `Line` **minus** `1` byte for `=` **minus** `2` bytes for the two double quotes and *most likely* **minus** `1` byte for terminating null byte. So in real `8182` (character index of character 8183) could be used instead of `8192` in the loop as absolute maximum.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

PS: The usage of any other scripting language/interpreter than Windows command processor `cmd.exe` designed for execution of commands and applications would be definitely better for the task counting commas and dots in a text file.