# How can I find my error in the batch script?

Tags: batch-file

The code below should archive some files by moving them into a subfolder. The batch file asks the user for the folder path. Then a subfolder should be created and if that was successful, it should move all files in the user input directory into the subdirectory. It works, but it closes although using `pause`. It does not output anything about a syntax error or anything at all. Please let me know if somebody notices something.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Insert path: 
set /p path=
echo the path is %path%
cd %path%

echo The files will be moved to a new folder
pause
mkdir %path%\archived_files
IF EXIST "archived_files" ( 
    for /f %%A in ('DIR /A /D /B') do (
        echo %%A && move /Y %path%\%%A %path%\archived_files) 
    echo Folder "archived_files" created or already exists
) else ( echo Folder "archived_files" does not exist )

echo the files have been transferred

pause
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Never, ever use `path` as a user-variable. It's a "magic variable" set by the operating system that tells windows where to look for executables that are not located in the current directory. Use another name.

Comment: The first step to debugging batch scripts is to delete the `@echo off` line and running it to see what it does. The second step is to remember that `%PATH%` is a system variable and you should never change its value unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: One of the best ways to debug your file is to check the usage information for each of the commands it uses. You can do that by invoking those commands with their built-in help argument. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?` and read the presented information. You should note that you very likely do not want to list files in wide column sorted format, `/D`, and more likely wished to output content which did not carry a directory attribute instead, i.e. `/A` with `-D`. For example `DIR /A:-D /B`, or `DIR /A-D /B`. You can do that similarly with `cd /?`, which also has a `/D` option.

Comment: ... and of course: don't execute it by "doubleclicking". Open a `cmd` window and start it from there. This way, the Window will stay open, enabling you to read any errormessages.

Comment: Thank you all, I made the changes and I found the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use this batch file for the file moving task.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BatchFileName=%~nx0"
set "BatchFilePath=%~dp0"
set "UserPath=%~1"
if defined UserPath goto ChangeFolder
:UserPrompt
set "UserPath="
set /P "UserPath=Enter path: "
rem Has the user not entered a string?
if not defined UserPath goto UserPrompt
rem Remove all double quotes from input string.
set "UserPath=%UserPath:"=%"
rem Has the user entered just one or more double quotes?
if not defined UserPath goto UserPrompt
:ChangeFolder
pushd "%UserPath%" 2>nul || (echo Folder "%UserPath%" does not exist.& goto UserPrompt)
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B 2^>nul') do goto CreateSubfolder
echo The folder does not contain any file to archive.& goto EndBatch
:CreateSubfolder
md "archived_files" 2>nul
if not exist "archived_files\" echo Failed to create subfolder: "archived_files"& goto EndBatch
rem It must be avoided that the currently running batch file is moved too.
set "ExcludeFileOption="
for %%I in ("%UserPath%\") do set "CurrentFolderPath=%%~dpI"
if "%CurrentFolderPath%" == "%BatchFilePath%" set "ExcludeFileOption= /XF "%BatchFileName%""
rem The command MOVE used with wildcard * does not move hidden files. A FOR loop
rem with MOVE is slow in comparison to usage of ROBOCOPY to move really all files.
rem The ROBOCOPY option /IS can be removed to avoid moving same files existing
rem already in the subfolder archived_files from a previous batch execution.
echo The files are moved to a new folder.
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe . archived_files%ExcludeFileOption% /MOV /R:2 /W:5 /IS /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS
if not errorlevel 2 if errorlevel 1 echo All files are moved successfully.
:EndBatch
popd
endlocal
pause
```

The batch file can be started with a a folder path as argument. So it is possible to right click on the batch file and click in opened context menu in submenu **Send to** on item **Desktop (create shortcut)**. The `.lnk` file created on the user´s desktop  can be renamed now also via context menu or key <kbd>F2</kbd> to whatever name is useful like `Archive files`. Then the shortcut file can be cut with <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> and pasted with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> in the folder `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` to have in **Send to** context submenu the menu item `Archive files`. This makes it possible to right click on a folder and click in opened context menu in submenu **Send to** on `Archive files` to run the batch file without the need to enter a folder path manually.

The batch file prompts the user for the path if not started with a folder path as first argument or the folder cannot be found at all. This user prompt is done using a safe method. The batch file makes the passed or entered folder temporarily the current folder for the remaining commands using **PUSHD** and **POPD** instead of **CD** to work also with [UNC paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention).

There is checked next if the folder contains any file at all. Otherwise the user is informed that the directory does not contain files to archive and batch file ends without any further action.

The file movement is done with **ROBOCOPY** for the reasons described in a remark in the batch file which requires Windows Vista or a newer Windows version or Windows Server 2003 or a newer Windows server version.

I recommend to see also:

- [Debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) which answers your question.
- [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It explains why `path` as name for the environment variable to assign the user entered path is a really bad idea.
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) It explains the reasons for using the additional code to evaluate the string entered by the user.
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains the recommended syntax for the (re)definition of an environment variable and why using this syntax.
- [Syntax error in one of two almost-identical batch scripts: ")" cannot be processed syntactically here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564) describes several common issues made by beginners in batch file coding like not enclosing a file/folder path in double quotes.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~nx0`, `%~dp0` and `%~1` whereby argument 0 is always the batch file itself.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `pause /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Other useful documentations used to write this code:

- [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- the Microsoft documentations for the used [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- the SS64 documentations for the used [Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/), especially:

  - [ROBOCOPY.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)
  - [ROBOCOPY Exit Codes](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html)
- the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))
  and the SS64 documentation [How-to: Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

**Note:** The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.