# Batch files inside folder to create MediaInfo.nfo file

Tags: batch-file, directory, mediainfo

I'm trying to create a Batch whose purpose is to use MediaInfo.exe (CLI) to create a single text file (.nfo) containing all the "mediainfo" of the video files contained in a folder.

The Batch is executed from the context menu: right click on the folder containing the video files.
To do so, the file will be placed in "shell:sendto".

The generated .nfo file containing all the mediainfo has to be "placed/saved or move" in the folder containing the video files.

A specificity is that i need to alter the final .nfo file, in order to delete all the path part of the lines "Complete name" :

```
Complete name                            : /Users/me/Downloads/Folder1/Folder2/RÉCENTS/[File] File Name - 185  (Encode Format 1080p).mkv
```

in this example : Do a search & replace to leave only :

```
Complete name                            : [File] File Name - 185  (Encode Format 1080p).mkv
```

---

For the moment, I've managed to create this batch (link below).
This one has a few bugs, namely :

- File not found (x2)
- Powershell that bugs if there are special characters

**To summarize process searched by the Batch :**

**1.** Right click on the folder containing the files > send to > click on the Batch file.

**2.** Creation of all the Media info txt files of the files contained in the folder

**3.** Merge Media Info txt files by adding a separator between each content "----".

**4.** Search & Replace on the final file with a Regex to remove all path before filename, then save (.nfo) inside the folder.

**5.** Clean the old temporary files from step 2.

[The actual Batch files I managed to create](https://pastebin.com/Ya2Nux4u) :

```
@echo off
 
:: Fullpath current folder : %cd%
:: Fullpath folder where the right click was made : %~f1
:: Name of the folder where the right click was made : for %%f in ("%~f1") do set Name=%%~nxf
 
for %%f in ("%~f1") do set Name=%%~nxf
 
:: Step 1: Creating a temporary folder
mkdir "%~f1-Temp"
 
:: Step 2: Creation of all nfo txt files in the temporary folder
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir "%~f1" /b *.mkv') DO (
   call "C:\Users\me\Desktop\MediaInfo\MediaInfo.exe" "%~f1\%%G" > "%~f1-Temp\%%~nG.txt"
)
 
:: Step 3: Filling in the final nfo
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
 
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir "%~f1" /b *.mkv') DO (
   IF !i! == 1 (
     echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ >> "%~f1-Temp\%Name%.txt"
     echo. >> "%~f1-Temp\%Name%.txt"
     echo. >> "%~f1-Temp\%Name%.txt"
  )
   cat "%~f1-Temp\%%~nG.txt" >> "%~f1-Temp\%Name%.txt" 
   set i=1
)
endlocal
 
:: Step 4: Removing the path
setlocal
set $source="%~f1-Temp\%Name%.txt"
set $dest="%~f1-Temp\%Name%1.txt"
set "search=%~f1\\"
 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -c "(get-content '%$source%') | foreach-object {$_ -replace '(?<=Complete name\s+:\s+).+\\'} | set-content '%$dest%'"') do echo %%a
endlocal
 
:: Step 5: Renaming the nfo and moving to the right place
Ren "%~f1-Temp\%Name%1.txt" "%Name%.nfo"
move "%~f1-Temp\%Name%.nfo" "%~f1"
 
:: Step 6: Deleting temporary files
rmdir /s /q "%~f1-Temp"
 
pause
```

If you have suggestions for improvement or/and corrections of what is already coded, don't hesitate!
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've created an issue yourself, by providing MediaInfo with the full path as the argument. If you just provide it with the filename, the `Complete name` will reflect just the filename.

In addition, unless I'm misunderstanding your intention, you're jumping through many hoops when I do not believe they are necessary.

The following example batch file should be created in your usual scripts directory, or even 'Documents' if you prefer.

Then you should create a shortcut to it in your 'SendTo' directory, giving it a name which you'll understand, perhaps `MediaNFO`.

Now all you should need to do is right click on your directory and choose `Send to` ➡ `MediaNFO`. This should create a file within the right clicked directory, with the same name as that directory, and containing the `mediainfo` output for every supported file it contains. The `Complete name` line should not include the path information, only the `File name`.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "MIExe=%UserProfile%\Standalone\MediaInfo\MediaInfo.exe"
Set "OutExt=nfo"
Set "HR=------------------------------------------------------------------"

For %%G In ("%~1") Do If "%%~aG" Lss "d" (If "%%~aG" GEq "-" (
        Echo Error! File arg.
        GoTo EndIt) Else (Echo Error! Invalid directory arg.
        GoTo EndIt)) Else If "%%~dG" == "" (
    Echo Error! Full directory path required.
    GoTo EndIt)

If Not Exist "%MIExe%" (Echo Error! MediaInfo not found.
    GoTo EndIt)

PushD "%~1"

Set "ExtLst="
For %%G In (aac ac3 aifc aiff ape asf au avi avr dat dts flac iff ifo irca m1v
    m2v mac mat mka mks mkv mov mp2 mp3 mp4 mpeg mpg mpgv mpv ogg ogm paf pvf qt
    ra rm rmvb sd2 sds vob w64 wav wma wmv xi) Do If Not Defined ExtLst (
    Set "ExtLst=".":"*.%%G"") Else Call Set "ExtLst=%%ExtLst%% ".":"*.%%G""

Set "}=%PATHEXT%" && Set "PATHEXT="
%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /Q %ExtLst%
If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo Error! Directory has no supported files.
    GoTo EndIt)

Set "i="
(For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe %ExtLst% 2^> NUL'
) Do (If Defined i Echo %HR%
    "%MIExe%" "%%~nxG"
    Set "i=T")) 1> "%~nx1.%OutExt%"

:EndIt
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
GoTo :EOF
```

You can change the location of `mediainfo.exe` on line `4`, and the output extension, on line `5`; but nothing else should be modified.

You should also note that I've added some input validation to this script. If your input directory is not a fully qualified directory path containing supported files for an existing mediainfo executable, it will report an error and close.

Comment: Hello @Compo, thanks it work perfectly.
On the other hand, I don't only have .mkv files but any kind of video file (.avi.mp4.mkv,...) if it's possible to add them inside the InExt check ?

Comment: I also want to add the possibility to do the batch directly on a file (.nfo save in the same place as the video file), for now it saved it at the Batch location.

Comment: I have replaced the code in my answer above to cater for all filetypes supported by mediainfo, from a quick look [here](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Support/Formats). @use2276368, despite you not having mentioned that requirement in your question. However, you specified that you were right-clicking on a folder, and your supplied code was using a folder input. There was absolutely no mention of right-clicking on a file, so unfortunately that is a different task and new question. However, with the techniques and advice offered in your two answers, you should try to code that yourself.

Comment: Hello @Compo, thanks a lot !
i will check to tweak it for single file too.. I hope to get there !

Comment: i have made a new question because i dont understand how to create nfo file without the path before the file for single.. : [The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66217438/2276368)

Comment: @Compo how can I add such that `mediainfo  --Inform=file://template.txt` gets operated on each file Basically I want a summarized output in .nfo

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Windows CMD versus PowerShell

The Windows command processor (`cmd.exe`) is processing a batch file. Its successor is the much more powerful script interpreter PowerShell (`powershell.exe`). The usage of PowerShell within a batch file does not really make sense as in this case it would be better to do the entire task with a PowerShell script using PowerShell syntax. For that reason I wrote a pure Windows command processor solution.

### 2. File/folder name not enclosed in double quotes

A file/folder name should be always referenced enclosed in `"` as otherwise a batch file could fail to process file/folder names containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. Most argument strings referencing a file or folder name are enclosed in double quotes in code posted in question, but some are not.

See: [Syntax error in one of two almost-identical batch scripts: “)” cannot be processed syntactically here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564)

### 3. Wrong usage of command DIR

The first **FOR** loop is not working as it should:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir "%~f1" /b *.mkv') DO (
```

The command **DIR** is executed by one more command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments to output in bare format (just file/folder name without path) all files/folders in directory specified with `%~f1` and all files/folders matching the pattern `*.mkv` in current directory on batch file execution. That is not correct. Correct would be `dir "%~f1\*.mkv" /A-D /B` to output just the names of all files with file extension `.mkv` in the directory referenced with `%~f1`.

The two file not found error messages are output most likely because of no `*.mkv` file/folder is found in the current directory whatever is the current directory on execution of the batch file.

The file names are output by **DIR** without path, except option `/S` is used for a recursive search. That must be taken into account on processing the file names output by **DIR** which is not done in batch code posted in the question.

### 4. Enabled delayed expansion not good on processing file names with a FOR loop

Enabling [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) above a **FOR** loop processing file names, or lines in a text file, or lines captured from standard output of a command process executed in background, is not good because it results in parsing a command line within the command block executed by **FOR** for each file name a second time before execution. A file/folder name or line containing one or more exclamation mark is not correct processed in this case because of `!` is interpreted by `cmd.exe` on second parsing as start/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference and not as literal character of file name or line.

See: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

### 5. cat is not a Windows command

`cat` is not a [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands). That is a tool ported from Unix/Linux to Windows or executed on Windows 10 using [Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

For that reason it is better to avoid the usage of `cat` as not available by default on Windows depending on version of Windows and user´s configuration.

### 6. Command CALL is of no use on running an executable

The command **CALL** is of no use on running an executable from within a batch file. It is the default behavior of Windows command processor to run the executable and wait for self-termination before processing the next command line in batch file.

The command **CALL** is mainly needed for calling a batch file from within a batch file.

The usage of command **CALL** on a command line just running an executable makes the processing of the batch file just slower because of `cmd.exe` processes in this case the command line a second time similar to usage of delayed expansion before executing the command line.

### 7. Batch file for collecting video information in one .nfo file

I don't have the tool *MediaInfo* installed nor do I have MKV files or other video files. It is perhaps enough to make the directory of which path is passed to the batch file the current directory and run `MediaInfo.exe` with just name of a video file in that directory to get the `Complete name` information written into the file without path. *MediaInfo* seems to be a tool ported also from Unix/Linux as it outputs the complete name of the video file without drive letter and colon and with `/` instead of `\`. The backslash is the directory separator on Windows as it can be read in the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Batch file code not using PowerShell or `cat`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "MediaInfoTool=%UserProfile%\Desktop\MediaInfo\MediaInfo.exe"

rem Assign the folder path passed to batch file to environment variable FolderPath.
set "FolderPath=%~1"
rem Use the batch file path if started without a folder path argument.
if not defined FolderPath set "FolderPath=%~dp0"
rem Remove all double quotes from folder path.
set "FolderPath=%FolderPath:"=%"
if not defined FolderPath set "FolderPath=%~dp0"
rem Replace all slashes by backslashes in folder path.
set "FolderPath=%FolderPath:/=\%"
rem Make sure the folder path ends with a backslash.
if not "%FolderPath:~-1%" == "\" set "FolderPath=%FolderPath%\"

rem Check existence of folder and output an error message if not existing.
if not exist "%FolderPath%" echo ERROR: Could not find folder: "%FolderPath%"& goto EndBatch
rem Check existence of any video file in folder and output an error message if not existing.
if not exist "%FolderPath%*.avi" if not exist "%FolderPath%*.mp4" if not exist "%FolderPath%*.mpg" if not exist "%FolderPath%*.mkv" echo ERROR: There is no *.avi or *.mp4 or *.mpg or *.mkv file in folder: "%FolderPath%"& goto EndBatch
rem Check existence of MediaInfo executable and output an error message if not existing.
if not exist "%MediaInfoTool%" echo ERROR: Could not find file: "%MediaInfoTool%"& goto EndBatch

rem Get just the folder name without path and full qualified folder name.
for %%I in ("%FolderPath%.") do set "FolderName=%%~nxI" & set "FolderPath=%%~fI"
rem Make sure the following environment variable is not defined.
set "Separator="
(for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%FolderPath%\*.avi" "%FolderPath%\*.mpg" "%FolderPath%\*.mp4" "%FolderPath%\*.mkv" /A-D /B') do (
    if defined Separator (
        echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        echo(
        echo(
    )
    set "Separator=1"
    set "OutputLine="
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ('^""%MediaInfoTool%" "%FolderPath%\%%I" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^"^"') do (
        set "InfoLine=%%J"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if defined OutputLine (
            echo(!InfoLine:*:=!
            endlocal
        ) else if "!InfoLine::Complete name=!" == "!InfoLine!" (
            echo(!InfoLine:*:=!
            endlocal
        ) else (
            for /F "tokens=1* delims=/" %%K in ("!InfoLine:*:=!") do endlocal& echo %%K%%~nxL
            set "OutputLine=1"
        )
    )
))>"%FolderPath%\%FolderName%.nfo"
if exist "%FolderPath%\%FolderName%.nfo" echo INFO: Video information written into file: "%FolderPath%\%FolderName%.nfo"

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

**ATTENTION:** The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` is not designed for processing file names with Unicode characters in name. So if a solution is needed to work really for all file names including those with Unicode characters in name, it is necessary to code a PowerShell script for the task and use `powershell.exe` as script interpreter.

Most command lines are explained with remarks using command **REM** in the batch files itself.

Here is a description of the **FOR** loop for processing all AVI, MP4, MPG and MKV files in specified directory with an inner **FOR** loop to run the tool *MediaInfo* and process the output lines with modification of the line with `Complete name` to remove the Unix/Linux path.

The most outer **FOR** starts in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line with **DIR** appended as additional arguments.

The command **DIR**

- searches in the directory referenced with `%FolderPath%`
- just for files because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- matching one of the four wildcard patterns `*.avi`,`*.mp4`, `*.mpg` or `*.mkv` and
- outputs just the file names without path in bare format because of option `/B`.

There should not be an error message output because of the **IF** condition used above to **FOR** loop to check the existence of any video file before running the **FOR** loop at all. The **IF** condition prevents the creation of an `.nfo` file in the specified directory on not containing a video file at all.

The output of **CMD** internal command **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** of background command process is captured by `for` respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores always empty lines which does not matter here on file names list. A line with a file name would be split up by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. A file name can contain one or more spaces at beginning and also in the middle. For that reason option `delims=` is used to specify an empty list of delimiters to prevent splitting up the file name into substrings (tokens). If the first substring (token) starts with a semicolon, the line is also ignored by **FOR** because of `;` is the default end of line character. A file name can have `;` at beginning although this is very unusual. Therefore option `eol=|` is used to define a vertical bar as the end of line character which no file name can contain ever. `"tokens=*"` is not useful as it results in removing first a leading spaces from file name and if the remaining file name starts with a semicolon, the file name is ignored by **FOR**.

So a file name without path is assigned to the specified loop variable `I`, even on having the unusual name   `;Video 100% & Test (1)!`.

A separator line and two empty lines are output if the currently processed file name is not the name of the first video file output by **DIR** (unsorted respectively as sorted by the file system). The environment variable `Separator` is explicitly undefined above the **FOR** loop and is (re)defined on each iteration of the outer **FOR** loop. The value assigned to the environment variable `Separator` does not matter.

See DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) for the reason using `echo(` instead of `echo.` to output empty lines.

The environment variable `OutputLine` is explicitly undefined before running *MediaInfo* and is later defined on having found the line with `Complete name`. It is used to speed up the processing of the information lines once the line `Complete name` was processed as in this case all other lines can be simply output without any further special processing.

The tool *MediaInfo* is executed also by starting in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional argument. For that reason it is very important to know how `cmd.exe` processes the argument string(s) after option `/C`. That is tricky as the processing of the argument string(s) depends on several conditions explained by the help output on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`. In this case it is necessary to enclose the entire command line in `"` to run background command process with correct command line as argument string.

But the batch file is processed also by `cmd.exe`. So the **FOR** command line must contain the command line to execute by background command process in a manner being valid for both `cmd.exe`. This is the reason why `"` at beginning and at end of the entire command lines and also the redirection operator `|`  are escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal characters by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. The command line enclosed in `"` passed to started `cmd.exe` does not contain the caret characters anymore.

The output of *MediaInfo* is redirected to **FINDSTR** which runs a regular expression find matching all lines and therefore outputs all lines with a line number and a colon according to option `/N`. This is done to make sure no line captured finally by **FOR** is a completely empty line which should be finally also in the NFO file and not silently ignored by **FOR**.

The lines output by *MediaInfo* extended by **FINSTR** with a line number and a colon at beginning are captured by **FOR** respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and are processed line by line after started background command process terminated itself.

The current line is first assigned as is to the environment variable `InfoLine` while delayed expansion is disabled to prevent interpretation of `!` as start/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference.

Delayed environment variable expansion is enabled next. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** as there happens more in the background than just enabling delayed expansion.

The current line is just output if the environment variable `OutputLine` is defined already with removal of the line number and the colon at beginning of the line to output the line as output in background command process by *MediaInfo*.

Otherwise there is made a case-sensitive string comparison of the current line with all occurrences of `:Complete name` (colon after line number and the string `:Complete name`) removed case-insensitive with the line not modified at all. If line with string substitution is equal the line without string substitution, this line from *MediaInfo* does not contain at beginning the string `Complete name` and is therefore also just output with removal of line number and colon.

Otherwise the line with `Complete name` is found in captured output of *MediaInfo*. For that reason the line with line number and colon at beginning removed is split up into two substrings. The first substring is `Complete name` with the whitespaces and the colon up to first `/` in the line which is assigned to loop variable `K`. The second substring is everything after first `/` up to end of the line which is assigned to next but one loop variable according to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is the letter `L`.

Delayed expansion is disabled first before the beginning of the line and the file name without path are output by the third **FOR** command line. Next the environment variable `OutputLine` is defined now to just output all further lines of *MediaInfo*.

Everything output to standard output of command process processing the batch file during processing the video files is redirected into a file with folder name with file extension `.nfo` in the specified folder.

The media information file was successful on file `.nfo` finally existing (and the information file did not exist already on starting the batch file and was additionally write-protected by read-only attribute, NTFS permissions or file access permissions).

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cmd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

The batch file can be run also from within a Windows command prompt window or PowerShell console without or with a folder path which can be also a relative path.