# Batch script cannot read file if there is a space

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

```
CD "C:\Input"
for %%a in ("*.*") do "C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i %%a -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -b:a 640K "C:\Out\%%~na.mkv"
pause
```

if there is no space this script works fine, but if there is a space in file name, the script reads only the first word of the file and throws an error. i tried to add a double quote first %%a. but then the script does not even run.

here is an example file name:
`[TEST] ABC test - 99`

Comment: Double-quoting the first `%%a` *should* have worked - you *did* retain the space after the `-i` didn't you? Try using `%%~sa` to use the shortname. "Doesn't run" - does what? simply appears to miss the `ffmpeg` command?

Comment: if i use double quote the first `%%a`, batch file is just open and close. yes there is a space before `-i`.

Comment: When you say you tried to add quotes to the first %%a do you mean this "for %%a" or this "-i %%a "?

Answer (score 2):

This can be resolved by putting quotes around the input filename:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do "C:\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%~a" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -b:a 640K "C:\Out\%%~na.mkv"
```

Comment: There can be used just `"%%a"` instead of `"%%~a"` as `for` assigns the found file name always without double quotes  to the loop variable `a`. So there is no need to use `%~a` to remove perhaps existing surrounding double quotes as there are never surrounding double quotes in this case. It is possible to use `a` as loop variable in this case, but it would be better to use a different character,  a character not being also a modifier, see [Issue 7: Usage of letters ADFNPSTXZadfnpstxz as loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564).