# Windows CMD Batch Looping Through Directories to Create New File Based on Existing File

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with over 500 folders.  In each folder is a single file.  I need to create a text file with the same name of the existing file.

Here is what I've tried

```
@echo off
pushd D:\StartFolder\
for %%d in (*.*) do (
    >nul cd "%%~nxd"
    for %%F in (*.*) do (
        type nul > "%%~nF.txt"
    )
    >nul cd..
)
popd
```

I don't seem to be pulling the directory.  Not sure if I need to use something other than *.* for the set.

Comment: You are using `%%F` before (outside) the corresponding `for` loop. `cd "%%~nF"` should probably be `cd %%~nd` (or better `%%~nxd`)

Comment: @Stephan Changed to %%~nxd but same result. :(

Comment: The entire posted batch code can be replaced by: `@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "D:\StartFolder\*" /A-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do @type NUL>"%%~dpnI.txt"` Open a command prompt window, run `dir /?`, `for /?` and `type /?` and read each output usage help carefully and completely. I described this command line in full details several times on Stack Overflow. Please let me know if you don't understand how this command line works from the helps and I will write an answer explaining this command line in full details with information which cannot be read in the output usage helps.

Comment: @Mofi I JUST got it working right before I read you reply.  I changed it to for `for /D %%d in (*) do (`  I will take your code and pick it apart to see how it works, thank you for this.

Comment: @Mofi Is the '%%I' for the '"delims=' just a variable and could be any letter?  And why the '2^>null' in the dir statement?  Everything else made sense :)

Comment: Read __Issue 7: Usage of letters ADFNPSTXZadfnpstxz as loop variable__ in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564). `I` can be in general any [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) letter, but it is advisable not using the letters which are also modifiers for __FOR__. A few other ASCII characters are also possible like `#`. `2^>nul` suppresses the error message output by __DIR__ on not finding any file in the entire directory tree by redirecting it from handle __STDERR__ to the device __NUL__.

Comment: Read the Microsoft doc about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on __FOR__ command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command __FOR__ which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c dir "D:\StartFolder\*" /A-D-L /B /S 2>nul`

Comment: `"delims="` defines an empty list of delimiters. There are used by default normal space/horizontal tab as string delimiters on processing a line captured from standard output stream of `cmd.exe` executed in background. The fully qualified file names output by __DIR__ line by line would be split up by __FOR /F__ on first space found in line (tab not possible in file/folder names) and just the part up to first space would be assigned to the loop variable. The usage of `"delims="` turns off the line splitting behavior and the entire file name is always assigned to the loop variable.