# Batch file with argument with escape character ^

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

I'm trying to call the batch script with password looking like:

```
ABC^=abc
```

Unfortunately, all my tries finish with result of:

```
ABC=abc
```

The "^" character is omitted and I don't know how to force in script to read argument with this char.

I have the line of code (where PASS is localization of file with passwords):

```
:get_pass
    set PASS=%~1
    set USR=%~2
    set passwd=

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (%PASS%) do (
      if %%a==%USR% (
        set "passwd=%%b"
      )
    )
```

And I call this func in command line:

```
    call script.cmd get_pass C:\Doc\pass.ini USR do set passwd=%%i
    echo %passwd%
    -> ABC=abc
```

The result is always without ^ char. I've tried a different combination of double quotes around argument like: "passwd=%%b", passwd="%%b", but it didn't work.

I'll be very grateful for your help!

Thanks,
Kamil

Comment: The help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window explains on last help page that a file name or any other argument string like a password must be enclosed in `"` on containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` or literally to interpret `<>|` which a file name cannot contain. The password must be passed to the batch file for that reason with `"ABC^=abc"`. Inside the batch file must be used also `"` around every usage of the password. `set PASS=%~1` should be `set "PASS=%~1"`. `set USR=%~2` should be `set "USR=%~2"`. `set passwd=` should be `set "passwd="`.

Comment: See also: [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains in full details why the recommended syntax is `set "variable=value"` with the double quotes as shown here. The batch file should have as second command line after `@echo off` also `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` to correct interpret the argument strings and assign them to environment variables independent on what is defined outside of the batch file as execution environment.

Comment: The __FOR__ loop must be modified to `for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims= " %%G in ("%PASS%") do if "%%G" == "%USR%" set "passwd=%%H" & goto HavePassword` and the next but one line is `:HavePassword` while the next line is `echo ERROR: User "%USR%" not found in password list file!& exit /B 1`. Read the __issue__ chapters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564) for more details.

Comment: The command line `call script.cmd get_pass C:\Doc\pass.ini USR do set passwd=%%i` is nonsense and will never work. The Microsoft online documentation for the command [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call) is updated after a request by me and explains the possible syntax like the usage help output on running `call /?` in a command prompt window. It is __impossible__ to call a batch file with its file name __and__ a label inside the batch file.

Comment: The command __CALL__ can be used either for calling another batch file from within a batch file or __CALL__ a command block below a label in same batch file for executing it like a subroutine or like this block would be in a separate batch file. Read also: [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564) The only command capturing the output of a program or script is `for /F`. The command line used by you calls `script.cmd` and passes the strings `get_pass`, `C:\Doc\pass.ini`, `USR`, `do`, `set`, `passwd=%%i` to it whereby `=` is interpreted as separator.

Comment: There can be used either `echo "%passwd%"` to get output `"ABC^=abc"` with the double quotes or `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !passwd!& endlocal` to output just `ABC^=abc` without the double quotes if the environment variable `passwd` is really defined with the string value `ABC^=abc` as it can be seen also on using in the batch file `set passwd` which outputs all environment variables of which name begins case-insensitive with the string `passwd` with name, equal sign and current value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct value is already stored in the variable, but your `echo %passwd%` is the problem.

You could check the value by

```
set passwd
```

And use the value with delayed expansion instead

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !passwd!
```