# Having issues parsing cropdetect values from ffmpeg in batch script

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, crop

I have this script that I'm trying to write that finds video files in a dir, automatically removes black bars and transcodes to x265...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Loop through all video files in the current directory
for %%F in (*.mp4, *.avi, *.mkv, *.ts) do (
    echo Processing "%%F"

    REM Use FFMPEG to detect crop values
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('ffmpeg -i "%%F" -vf "cropdetect" -f null - 2^>^&1 ^| find /i "crop="') do (
        set cropfilter=%%a
    )

    REM Extract the crop filter result
    set cropfilter=!cropfilter:*crop=! 
    set cropfilter=!cropfilter: =!

    REM Use the detected crop filter to crop the video
    if not "!cropfilter!"=="" (
        echo Detected crop filter: !cropfilter!
        ffmpeg -i "%%F" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s? -c:v:0 libx265 -crf 18 -vf "crop=!cropfilter!" -c:a:0 aac -ac 2 -b:a:0 256k -c:a:1 aac -ac 6 -b:a:1 512k -c:s copy "encoded.mkv"
    ) else (
        echo No cropping needed for "%%F".
    )
)

echo Processing complete.
pause
```

I'm struggling to correctly parse the crop values output from the initial ffmpeg query though. What its grabbing at the moment is:

```
detect_0@000001ce4b0e2040]x1:0x2:1919y1:131y2:948w:1920h:816x:0y:132pts:625483604t:6949.817822limit:0.094118crop=1920:816:0:132
```

When I really just need this bit:

```
crop=1920:816:0:132
```

So that I can call it in the transcode command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please open a command prompt window, run `for /?` and read the output usage help. `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in` results in getting the entire line output by `ffmpeg.exe` with leading spaces/tabs removed assigned to the loop variable `a` which you don't want. You want just everything after the first `=` which can be get by using `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in`. I recommend further reading the __issue__ chapters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564). Please note that your batch file cannot process correct videos with one or more `!` in file name.

Comment: The command lines `REM Extract the crop filter result` and `set cropfilter=!cropfilter:*crop=!` and `set cropfilter=!cropfilter: =!` are not needed on using the right options for `for /F`. There must be inserted below `echo Processing "%%F"` the line `set "cropfilter="` to make sure the environment variable `cropfilter` is undefined before running `ffmpeg`, filter its output with `find` and process the captured output with the `for /F` loop assigning everything after the first equal sign like `1920:816:0:132` to the redefined environment variable `cropfilter` on `crop=` output by `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Hint: Executables like `ffmpeg` or `find` can be found faster by `cmd.exe` on referencing them in the batch file with file extension `.exe` instead of just file name, i.e. `ffmpeg.exe` and `find.exe` instead of just `ffmpeg` and `find`. Best is the usage of the fully qualified file name on full path is well known like `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe` as in this case `cmd.exe` does not need to search for the executables at all avoiding thousands of file system accesses during batch file execution on processing dozens of videos in current directory.

Comment: Cheers Mofi, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 1):

Having set `cropfilter` to *nothing*, I'd suggest the following mods to your code:

```
...
    set "cropfilter=%%a"
)

REM Extract the crop filter result
set "cropfilter=!cropfilter:*crop=crop!"
set "cropfilter=!cropfilter: =!"
...
```

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

Note : your line

```
set cropfilter=!cropfilter:*crop=!
```

will remove all characters up to **and including** `crop` yielding `=1920:816:0:132`

**AND** the code line contains a terminal space, so that space will be included in the value `set`.

So - the replacement line will replace all characters up to **and including** `crop` with `crop` and there is no terminal space, so the second line is probably not needed.