# batch file how to get all tokens from a string

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, token

I have an issue with going through all tokens I get in a for loop.
I have a part of the batch file:

```
for %%f in ("*.my_file_type") do (
    set BaseName=%%~nf
    set ExportName=
    
    for /f "delims=_" %%a in ("!BaseName!") do (
        echo Word is %%a
        call :CapitalizeFirstLetter %%a
        set ExportName=!ExportName!!CapWord!
    )
...
)
```

So, the issue is that I am getting only first token, but I want all of them.
For example, I would have my files:

```
my_file_name
file_name
this_is_another_file_name
```

And I want to get correct file names. Right now, I want them like this:

```
MyFileName
FileName
ThisIsAnotherFileName
```

And right now, the issue is that I would get only this:

```
My
File
This
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%f in ("*.my_file_type") do (
    set BaseName=%%~nf
    set ExportName=
    
    for %%a in (!BaseName:_= !) do (
        echo Word is %%a
        call :CapitalizeFirstLetter %%a
        set ExportName=!ExportName!!CapWord!
    )
...
)
```

should fix your problem **(untried)**

---odd -----

This works:

```
SET "filenames=my_file_name file_name this_is_another_file_name"
for %%f in (%filenames%) do (
    set BaseName=%%f
    set ExportName=
    SET "basename=!BaseName:_= !"
    
    for %%a in (!BaseName!) do (
        echo Word is %%a
rem        call :CapitalizeFirstLetter %%a
        set ExportName=!ExportName!!CapWord!
    )
    ECHO "!exportname!"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be used the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "*.my_file_type" /A-D /B 2^> nul') do set "FullName=%%I" & call :RenameFile) & goto EndBatch

:RenameFile
for %%G in ("%FullName%") do set "FileName=%%~nG" & set "FileExt=%%~xG"
set "NewName="
:NamePart
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%G in ("%FileName%") do set "CapWord=%%G" & set "FileName=%%H" & call :Capitalize
set "NewName=%NewName%%CapWord%"
if defined FileName goto NamePart
ECHO ren "%FullName%" "%NewName%%FileExt%"
goto :EOF

:Capitalize
set "FirstChar=%CapWord:~0,1%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%J in ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" "k=K"
            "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V"
            "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z" "ä=Ä" "ö=Ö" "ü=Ü") do (
    if not "!FirstChar!" == "!FirstChar:%%~J!" set "FirstChar=!FirstChar:%%~J!" & goto CapDone
)
:CapDone
endlocal & set "CapWord=%FirstChar%%CapWord:~1%" & goto :EOF

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

**Note:** There is the command `ECHO` left to command `ren` which results in getting just output the rename command line instead of really doing it.

The command lines in the subroutine `RenameFile` below the label `NamePart` are executed as long as there is defined the environment variable `FileName`. The string value of this environment variable is reduced on each iteration of the **GOTO** loop until all underscore delimited parts of the file name passed to the subroutine `RenameFile` have been processed with a capitalization of the first character and the concatenation to the new name with the removal of all underscores.

The German umlauts must be encoded in the batch file with the code page as output on running `chcp` in a command prompt window like [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

The batch file was tested with a file named

```
this_is_a_file_name_for_development & test 100% (!).my_file_type
```

in the current directory on execution of the batch file which is renamed without `ECHO` to

```
ThisIsAFileNameForDevelopment & test 100% (!).my_file_type
```

Yes, it is hard to do string processing for which the *Windows Command Processor* is not designed for at all if the code should work for file names containing also characters like `!%&()`. The file name reformatting would be very simple with a regular expression replace supported by *PowerShell*.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on first **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background using `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line inside `'` append as additional arguments.

See also:

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [Why is a GOTO loop much slower than a FOR loop and depends additionally on power supply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362979/why-is-a-goto-loop-much-slower-than-a-for-loop-and-depends-additionally-on-power)
- The **issue** chapters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564) for the reason not using `f` and `a` as loop variables and enclosing file name strings always in `"` on referencing them.
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&`.